# Gitlab : Download artifacts from a job in another child pipeline

Tags: gitlab, pipeline

I want to download an Artifact in a job present in a Child pipeline from another job present in another Child pipeline part of the same parent-child pipeline hierarchy.

I tried with the files below that are inspired from the Gitlab documentation (see the paragraph "Example of needs:pipeline:job" in https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/) but **with no success** (I have this error : *This job depends on other jobs with expired/erased artifacts*)

parent.yml

```
parent1:
  stage: test
  trigger:
    include: child1.yml
    strategy: depend

parent2:
  stage: test
  trigger:
    include: child2.yml
    strategy: depend
  variables:
    PARENT_PIPELINE_ID: $CI_PIPELINE_ID
```

Child1.yml

```
create-artifact:
  stage: build
  script: echo "sample artifact" > artifact.txt
  artifacts:
    paths: [artifact.txt]
```

Child2.yml

```
use-artifact:
  script: cat artifact.txt
  needs:
    - pipeline: $PARENT_PIPELINE_ID
      job: create-artifact
```

So according to the official Gitlab documentation : *A child pipeline can download artifacts from a job in its parent pipeline or another child pipeline in the same parent-child pipeline hierarchy.* so I am wondering how to make it work in my example files?

Comment: Hi, it is not possible yet. See the issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/285100

Comment: Hello. You are trying to use it on the different parent-child pipeline hierarchy. Look into the documentation that you are mention - "in the same parent-child pipeline hierarchy"

Comment: I hear its possible by using commit-ref in your cache, then grabbing it from the cache

Comment: @blamb do you have and example of that that you could post as an anwser?

Comment: sorry I dont, id have to look it up again. I will check my browser history for it though.  I think i found it on a gitlab bug report page.

Comment: would be great, I have been reading and reading...still no solution